# Package download with Rstudio issue with proxy connection

Tags: proxy, server, package, rstudio

That's 2 days I'm looking on the internet for a solution to my problem without succes. 
I downloaded Rstudio at my job and I tried to install some packages.

When I put for example in R :

```
> install.packages("readxl")
```

It returns

```
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http ://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http ://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES'    
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘readxl’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http ://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http ://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES'    
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘readxl’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http ://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4:
  cannot open URL 'http ://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authorization Required'    
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4:
  cannot open URL 'http ://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES'
```

I looked on the internet and the problem seems to be the connection to the proxy of my company (I have to put username and password each time I connect to the internet)

I tried to add in the .Renviron file that is in C:\Users\your user name\Documents the following code that I found on internet :

```
options(internet.info = 0)   
http_proxy = https:// user_id:password@your_proxy:your_port    
http_proxy_user = user_id:password
```

I replaced the user_id and the password
I found my proxy in : start>run>cmd>ipconfig it is of the form xxxxx.xxx.ca (some letters replace the 'x')
And for my port I put 8080

I also tried to download directly the zip file of the package but it doesn't work neither.

I'm desperate to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing `.Renviron` in `C:\Users\your user name\`?